# Using geo_distance filter doesn't return any hits using ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation

I can't get my filter query to work correctly with geo_distance.  It seems to return 0 hits.  But all of my other queries work if I'm not trying to find a geo position.

I'm using version 2.3.1 of ElasticSearch

```
{
  "name" : "Mar-Vell",
  "cluster_name" : "elastic-logs",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I've mapped my location key with a type of "geo_point" by making a request with json like so:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://10.0.7.181:9200/connections/profile/_mapping' -d '
{

      "profile" : {
         "properties" : {
            "location" : {
               "type" : "geo_point"
            }
         }
      }
}
```

And it returns this. I'm assuming my changes are in affect.

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Here's an example of my data

```
  {
    "_index": "connections",
    "_type": "profile",
    "_id": "92",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "profile": {
        "location": {
          "lon": -111.8909815,
          "lat": 40.7607818
        },
        "age": 44,
        "school": {
          "undergraduate": {
            "universityId": 1814,
            "active": true,
            "programId": 9
          },
          "graduate": {
            "universityId": 1814,
            "active": true,
            "programId": 7
          }
        },
        "bio": "Everything is awesome! "
      },
      "id": 0,
      "active": false,
      "optIn": true
    }
  }
```

My query that I'm sending over to our ElasticSearch.  Nothing crazy.

```
{
   "filter" : {
      "geo_distance" : {
         "distance" : "1000mi",
         "distance_type": "plane",
         "location" : {
          "lon": -111.8391029,
          "lat": 40.7607818
         }
      }
   },
   "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   }
}
```

I've tried changing the distance to 1 mile, 100 miles and 1000 miles. It should return something with 100 miles but no show.  I've also tried using different unit measurements just to see if it would do anything.  The same deal.

The coordinates are in Salt Lake City. And the order of longitude and latitude should be right. I'm not sure what else I should try.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your location field is `location`, but in your query you are using `geoPoint` as the field name. Try this:

```
{
   "filter" : {
      "geo_distance" : {
         "distance" : "1000mi",
         "distance_type": "plane",
         "location" : {
          "lon": -111.8391029,
          "lat": 40.7607818
         }
      }
   },
   "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   }
}
```

**Update**: Ok, that was the obvious mistake i saw so I didn't look any further. Here is a working query(with your values) from one of my projects:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": []
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "1000mi",
          "distance_type": "plane",
          "location": {
            "lat": "-111.8391029",
            "lon": "40.7607818"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted the wrong code.  I made the changes to my example search query.  I was experimenting with a new property and I thought by creating a different property called "geoPoint" with a  type "geo_point" with the same values that it would have made a difference. I have previously tried searching by "location" with no luck.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer now with a working query from one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

@Pelmered thanks for helping me with the filter query.  I found out that my mapping was done incorrectly.  Now everything works as expected. So make sure you are mapping it correctly.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://10.0.7.181:9200/connections' -d '

{
   "mappings":{
      "profile":{
         "properties":{
            "location":{
               "type":"geo_point"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```